# My Session expires automatically after login in live server?

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm currently having an issue with the session expiration as soon as I login.But in localhost it is running perfectly fine.
Framework: Laravel 6

Comment: which code do you want ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If session is stored in files give the permission 777 to storage directory in you server. If you are storing the session in database then we have to find out other alternate solution.

Comment: I have'nt stored the session anywhere

Comment: Give the permission to storage directory in sever to 777. I am sure that problem will be solved.

Comment: could you please guide i'm kinda new in laravel

Comment: How are you accessing the files from server? If you have the FTP access navigate to storage directory.
Right click on storage directory. You will see the custom dialog with checkboxes. Check all the checkboxes also check Recursive into subdirectories and then press Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to the storage directory as 777,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /to/your/folder
```